# How can I query Azure logs by request response?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I see many API calls in my logs. I would like to group the calls by some attributes contained in the response.
I can see the response body in the log, and I can filter them in the transaction search, but I would like to create a query in the logs and group them by some attribute contained in the response.

In particular, the responses I'm interested in, contain a json object with an "email" attribute. I would like to group the API calls based on that email attribute.

If that's not possible, I could also count the API call based on a particular email, something like count() where "test@email.com" in response

Any hint on how to do that welcome

Answer (score 0):

Filter the specific substring of your response by using [**has_any**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-anyoperator) **Operator** in Azure log. Using this Operator, you can fetch multiple strings also with same column.

#### Workaround follows

Here I am using **has_any** operator to fetch specific string from the request and Using count operator to find the string available rows.

```sql
# KQL Query to fetch the specific string from response
requests
| where <column NAME> has_any ("<string you want to search from result>") 
| summarize count() by tostring(<Column NAME>)
```

#### Result

[image]